# Can I sue Lloyd's Bank on grounds of religious discrimination?

Tags: united-kingdom, discrimination

https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/home-news/lloyds-bank-removes-overdraft-fee-from-islamic-accounts-9291932.html

Does a bank have the right to disadvantage clients (overdraft charges) purely on the basis of their religious beliefs?

Can a client be excluded from a free overdraft facility based on their religion?

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't seem as if the bank is discriminating in the way you suggest. They offer two types of account: (A) accrues or charges interest and (B) does not accrue or charge interest. The bank says you can choose A or B whatever your religion. You the customer choose A or B, possibly depending on your religion. So I do not see what cause of action you have or what damages you have suffered. Therefore I don't think you could sue them.

Comment: Or, to be more precise, you can sue (as any adult who is literate and can front the filing fee may), but you would not prevail and your lawsuit would probably be dismissed early on, probably with some sort of sanction imposed upon you.

Comment: Stands to reason though doesn't it.

Answer (score 5):

You have clearly not read the article at all, but the headline, and decided to be offended.

Lloyds offers a bank account with alternative turns, with no overdraft charges, and with no interest payments. While it is muslims who are mostly interested in these accounts (and Lloyds took advice from experts), these bank accounts are open to *everybody*. You can have one, no matter what your religion. No discrimination.

Comment: Do you mean "alternative terms"?

Comment: Not at all offended. I think Islamic Finance should be open to everyone and am curious how Western banks will try and compete with it